# Abaqus won't submit job from cmd line

Tags: python, cmd, jobs, abaqus

I am trying to submit an Abaqus job from the cmd line without opening the cae. I have a script which I have successfully ran from the File->Run Script option within cae but for some reason when I try to get it to run from the cmd line without cae it returns an error that says the "job must refer to a valid model". It obviously is a valid model since it runs with the cae open.

I am typing

```
abq6142 noGUI=runjobtest.py
```

into the cmd line and my script looks like this

```
import os, glob 
import job
from abaqus import *
from abaqusConstants import *
openMdb('File_Name.cae')
myJob1 = mdb.Job(name='A01_AB', model='A01_As-Built', description='jobDescription')
myJob1.submit()
```

Comment: I just added the openMdb line and was able to make it work. However this didn't quite work the way I was hoping. The reason I wanted to make this work using the cmd line was to run a job without using licenses from opening the cae. We are limited in licenses so saving on the licenses to open the cae would be helpful. Submitting this job the way it is scripted still uses up licenses for opening cae and submitting the job.

Comment: you are looking at this wrong. In CAE if you make your job, then right click and "write input". This gives you a file called jobname.inp in your Abaqus working folder. If you then go to a command line. Navigate to teh abaqus folder (I think there is a start menu shortcut for "abaqus command") and then run it from there using "abaqus job=jobname.inp". This will run it without using CAE. This is clearly explained in teh Abaqus documentation.

Comment: this method works. My guess you've got the model name wrong or some other issue with your `cae`.  You can by the way do `model=mdb.models.keys()[0]`, assuming there is only one model in the cae then you dont need to worry about spelling the name correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaking here, I guess your command should be

```
abq6142 cae noGUI=runjobtest.py
```

and not

```
abq6142 noGUI=runjobtest.py
```

I guess you are missing `cae` argument in your cmd command